# How to Configure your Mobile site to work with Opera Mini's Single Column View

Tags: opera-mini

I have wanted to have a mobile site that works responsively like Facebook, Twitter, Google plus when a  person is using Opera Mini Browser with Single Column view to access my mobile site.

Some people have suggested things like using declaring on the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="handheld" type="text/css" href="./kh_themes/css/mobile.css">
```

but it has not always worked well for me and others coz I have never seen a working solution as I expected. Does anyone have an idea of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you view the source code for the facebook Mobile site you will see this code just before the  tag declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Welcome to Facebook</title>
```

I tried it on my site and it worked like charm. So if you have a mobile site add this code to your header section before the  tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Let me know how it works on your site: Dont forget to select my answer as the best;